# Does Lazarus have some kind of StringGrid that could support Virtual Mode just like a ListBox in .NET WinForm?

Tags: lazarus, tstringlist, virtualmode

I'd like to have a String Grid (or data grid) that could support Virtual Mode (loading data on-demand), I noticed that TListView has the OnData event that could do something similar, but I am not sure whether there is any grid control in Lazarus that could support this, or does TStringList support such Virtual Mode as well?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazarus comes with Virtual String Tree, which is a treeview control that can also be used for grids.  Search it in packages and install it, restart lazarus and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is super helpful.